# Calculating Spend from Revenue and ROI

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

I'm trying to figure out what the formula would be to generate the `Spend` if I know the `Revenue` and the `Return on Investment`.

Here is the formula on how to calculate the ROI: 
(Revenue - Spend) / Spend

And here is an example using the formula above:

```
Spend:      $100
Revenue:    $300
Profit:     $200
ROI:        200%
```

So with the formula and example above, how do I generate `Spend` if I have the `Revenue` and `ROI`?

Comment: @NormalHuman any suggestions? I tried a couple tags that didnt exist so the only 1 i could attach was percentages

Comment: This is a simple algebraic operation and I must believe that you can solve it yourself.  Try to rearrange the formula for ROI and you will get a formula for Spend

Comment: @satishramanathan ive been trying for a while can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S = Spend$

Let $R = Revenue$

Let $R_i = ROI$

You know $R_i = (R-S)/S$

Now, $SR_i = R-S$

$S(R_i+1) = R$

$S = \frac{R}{(1+R_i)}$

Comment: what is the `1`?

Comment: When you take S to the other side it becomes +S, you already have $SR_i$, when you take S out, you will get $S(1+R_i)$.  That's how you get 1

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: You are welcome!!